# BMW 3 series 320D 2010 brake light and inspection light

Tags: bmw, brake-fluid, warning-light

Today the trip computer went over the service due milage. After a short period the red inspection light came on and what appears to be the red brake fluid light?

Below is the closest picture I could find. Ignore the seatbelt sign but the other two stay on during traveling:

[image: Photo of another car showing indicators]

As soon as I got back I restarted the car and it was still on...

I checked the brake fluid and it was normal...

I checked each disk and pad to see if it was touching or there were leaks or scratches but nothing...

On the way back the brake felt as normal, testing after I reached home it seems to work. But it does go a bit soft after a hard press unless I pump the pedal then it goes hard.

Is this something that BMW is trying to scare you with? I.e., change your fluid every 1/2 years or is it that the system has air in it.

Either way I need an answer as I'm not sure to drive it to work in its current condition. Would it be safe?

Fault code is ccid 71.. suggest pads however visually they all look ok so I think it's a sensor?

Comment: It would help to know the year of the car, as the way that service and warnings are communicated can change from year to year.

Comment: Do you have access to the owner's manual for the car? In some cars (VW, for example) the lights are "overloaded" with other meanings – for example on a VW diesel Jetta the glow plug light also is used to indicate possible brake light problems. So a good starting place would be to look in the manual or do an online search for the combination of warning lights.

Comment: The year is 2010

Comment: And yes I do I will have a look asap.

Comment: If you can, it might help to post a picture of the lights that you're seeing and any other displays that are relevant. I found [this list of BMW warning lights](http://www.bmwoftowson.com/dash-indicator-lights.htm), I assume you're seeing the circle with the exclamation point and the car with the word service?

Comment: Yeah it's the circle with explanation

Answer (score 1):

I found this service icon and its description at a [UK BMW site](https://www.bmw-service.co.uk/service_icons),

[image: BMW brake fluid service annunciator]

So, it sounds like you might be right about BMW wanting to encourage you to get the fluid changed. It is not a bad idea, as brake fluid tends to pick up water over time which can both damage internal components and, under heavy braking, may lead to brake failure if the water boils causing you to loose hydraulic pressure.

It is also not a "must do today" (or even this week) thing. In the real world there are lots of cars with **very** old brake fluid.

Comment: See updates answer for picture